# wrong signals from limit switches when connected with pump

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, controller

I'm working on a project that requires using 3 motors, 2 limit switches, and a water pump.

I'm having a problem with the limits switches since the motors go reverse by themselves when it connected to the pump

important note: I used a 5v relay to control the pump using raspberry pi, however, the problem doesn't occur when the pump is disconnected, the relay works fine and no wrong signals from the limit switches, once the pump is connected to the relay , the motors got reversed and stoped by themselves.

I'm using the following code which seems to be fine with me:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import Controller

Right_PWM_1, Left_PWM_1, Right_Enable_1, Left_Enable_1 = 14, 18, 23, 24 # motor 1 (left)
Right_PWM_2, Left_PWM_2, Right_Enable_2, Left_Enable_2 = 26, 19, 13, 6 # motor 2 (right)
Right_PWM_3, Left_PWM_3, Right_Enable_3, Left_Enable_3 = 16, 20, 17, 27 # brush (right)
limit_switch_1, limit_switch_2, relay = 9, 11, 5

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(Right_PWM_1, GPIO.OUT),GPIO.setup(Left_PWM_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Right_Enable_1,GPIO.OUT),GPIO.setup(Left_Enable_1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(Right_Enable_1, True),GPIO.output(Left_Enable_1, True)
GPIO.setup(Right_PWM_2, GPIO.OUT),GPIO.setup(Left_PWM_2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Right_Enable_2,GPIO.OUT),GPIO.setup(Left_Enable_2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(Right_Enable_2, True),GPIO.output(Left_Enable_2, True)
GPIO.setup(Right_PWM_3, GPIO.OUT),GPIO.setup(Left_PWM_3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Right_Enable_3,GPIO.OUT),GPIO.setup(Left_Enable_3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(Right_Enable_3, True),GPIO.output(Left_Enable_3, True)
GPIO.setup(limit_switch_1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(limit_switch_2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)

Motor1 = Controller.Motor()
Motor2 = Controller.Motor()
Motor3 = Controller.Motor()
Pump = Controller.Pump()

try:
    while True:
        x = input("Start the program")
        if x == "y":

            if GPIO.input(limit_switch_1) == GPIO.LOW and GPIO.input(limit_switch_2) == GPIO.LOW:
                Motor1.backward(Right_PWM_1,Left_PWM_1)
                Motor2.backward(Right_PWM_2,Left_PWM_2)
                Motor3.forward(Right_PWM_3,Left_PWM_3)
                Pump.pump_on(relay)

                while True:
                    if GPIO.input(limit_switch_1) == GPIO.HIGH:
                        Motor1.forward(Right_PWM_1,Left_PWM_1)
                        Motor2.forward(Right_PWM_2,Left_PWM_2)
                        Motor3.backward(Right_PWM_3,Left_PWM_3)
                        Pump.pump_off(relay)
                        break
                    else:
                        pass

                while True:
                    if GPIO.input(limit_switch_2) == GPIO.HIGH:
                        Motor1.stop(Right_PWM_1,Left_PWM_1)
                        Motor2.stop(Right_PWM_2,Left_PWM_2)
                        Motor3.stop(Right_PWM_3,Left_PWM_3)
                        break
                    else:
                        pass

                Pump.pump_off(relay)

        elif x == "stop":
            break
        else:
            pass
except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Why is that happening ? the problem occurs when the pump is connected, otherwise the code and every thing works fine.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why is that happening ? the problem occurs when the pump is connected, otherwise the code and every thing works fine

Comment: So it seems it's an electrical problem and not a programming problem?

Comment: Or what is the code doing differently when the pump is connected?

Comment: the code works really code when the relay is connected ( as I want ), but when I connect the pump with the relay the motors go revers and stop by them selves which you can see in the code they shouldn't do that unless they revive a signal from the limit switches

Comment: Sorry, I can't see that, I can't look over your shoulders and don't know your hardware setup. You have to explain it: Which path is the code taking when the pump is not connected and which path is it taking when the pump is connected?